# Can a Lie group act transitively on a geometrically finite hyperbolic manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $ M $ be a hyperbolic manifold. If $ M $ has finite volume (this includes all compact hyperbolic manifolds of course) then [no Lie group can act transitively on $ M $](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454340/why-cant-a-lie-group-act-transitively-on-a-finite-volume-hyperbolic-manifold).

But what about geometrically finite hyperbolic manifolds? A hyperbolic manifold is called geometrically finite if the thick part of its convex core is compact.

Is it possible for a Lie group $ G $ to act transitively on a geometrically finite hyperbolic manifold $ M $?

Comment: Well, it can, for instance when the manifold is homeomorphic to $T^n\times {\mathbb R}$ or $D^n\times {\mathbb S}^1$ or when the manifold is ${\mathbb H}^{n+1}$ itself.